# Conversion error in pandoc referring to line outside of source file

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a latex document to docx (damn you journals that do not accept latex or pdf submissions), but get an error referring to a line outside the range of the latex source file (the file is 385 lines). I have checked the only instances of `\\` (within a table) and these seem unproblematic. The error also remains if the table is removed. The latex source compiles to pdf in MiKTeX.

The error occurs if I try to convert to other formats as well, so it is not an issue specific to docx conversion. It is hard to make a reproducible example since I dont know what part of the code that is causing the problem (since it is referring to a line number outside of the inputfile). Is the error message referring to the pandoc source?

Command:

```
 pandoc -f latex article.tex -o article.docx
```

Error message:

```
pandoc.exe:
Error:
"source" (line 407, column 1):
unexpected "\\"
expecting white space, "%", new-line, "begin", letter, "*", "[", "}", "egroup",  
"endgroup", "{", "bgroup", "begingroup", "-", "``", "`", "'", "~", "$$", "$", "^", "_",
"^^", "]", "#", "&", "\\" or "
end"
```

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot?

Don't know if this more suitable for Stackoverflow or http://tex.stackexchange.com, but there are more search hits for pandoc over here.

#### Edit:

I have now found out that the conversion works if the input file is moved to ./temp/input.tex, and I'm really confused. The associated files (.eps, .bib) was moved along with it, and files in both folders have been renamed so that no old temporary files are influencing the tex conversion. The original folder does not have any weird characters or white space. I'm even more confused and annoyed. However, at least I can get the converted file.

Comment: Can you trim down your article.tex file until it works?  I'm having a similar problem with some latex code generated by knitr and I found that an sprintf line with % in it would choke it.

Comment: Here's some trimmed code that works for LaTeX but chokes for Pandoc: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
main <- {sprintf("x = %5.3f",3.1415926)}
\end{alltt}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 5):

For your question about how to troubleshoot, try putting an \end{document} in places in your document.  If your issue is an element that can reach its closure in latex, but fails to close in pandoc, you might be able to locate the unclosed element by truncating the document at other places.

The following doesn't give exactly your error, but I was able to binary-search and pare down a much longer failing document to this bug using this \end{document} idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{alltt} 
main <- {sprintf("x = %5.3f",3.1415926)} 
\end{alltt} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm even more confused now though, since I've found out that the conversion works if I move the file (including the called .bib file) to ./temp/input.tex. And none of the folders have any weird characters in their names.

Comment: Just a note, in 2019, on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.10, I get an error like this with my document; and also with the short latex code you provide: `unexpected \end \end{alltt}`