# Pandoc error at source unexpected at \end{document}

Tags: latex, docx, pandoc, converters

I am trying to convert my file from Latex to pandoc, using pandoc, using the following code:

`pandoc -f latex Final_Paper_1.tex --bibliography=bibliography.bib --o helloworld.docx`

The program ran and responded with an error in the last line, as illustrated below:

```
Error at "Final_Paper_1.tex" (line 572, column 1):
unexpected \end
\end{document}
```

line 572 is actually the last line of my document, which contain `\end{document}`

I don't know why it is the case, I have actually tried to reinstall the program, modified the name of the latex file, and move it to other folders, as discussed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214806/conversion-error-in-pandoc-referring-to-line-outside-of-source-file)

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused when there is an unclosed curly bracket in the document, e.g.

```
Hello \emph{world}{ and all. This is a \textbf{sample} text.
```

pdflatex will give an error message like:

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)
### simple group (level 1) entered at line 1462
```

It seems that latex will ignore the extra curly bracket while pandoc will not. The tricky thing is that pandoc does not provide an error message at the actual place where this problem occurs.

Always solve all error messages in the Latex log before proceeding, even if Latex will ignore them.

Comment: it does not make much sense for it worked when I used the exact same code in overleaf, which probably had more packages preinstalled than my PC

Comment: This answer appears correct for me. I happened to have a latex file with unclosed `\noindent{` (shame on authors), causing the whole issue. Overleap uses the same latex engine and would ignore the issue as said in the answer @nikola-tolzsek.